# reinterpret_cast wrong values in Qt Debugger

Tags: c++, qt, windbg

I'm using QtCreator 4.8.0 with mingw 4.9.2, GDB 7.8 and Qt 5.6.3 and the following line of code is producing a wrong value, if run in the Debugger:

```
T* temp = reinterpret_cast<T*>(anArray.data());
```

`T`is `float` and `anArray` is a `QByteArray` with values `[40 A0 00 00]`. `40 A0 00 00` converted to float should actually be `5`, but for some weird reason it is evaluated as something around `-10^38`, but only if run in debug mode. When I start the program outside of the QtCreator Debugger the value is correctly calculated as `5`.
EDIT: On another machine the exact same code and combination of Qt, mingw, ... works absolutely fine.

I already tried to rebuild the entire Project but it doesn't change anything. Does anybody has an idea, how this happens? And more importantly how to fix it?

Comment: Is the data properly aligned? No endianness issues?

Comment: It is definitely no problem of endianness, since even if the byte order was swapped you wouldn't get anything near -10^38.

Comment: Try to provide MCVE which exhibits the issue. Problem is probably somewhere else... Undefined behavior somewhere.

Comment: Since this seems to be more a problem of QtCreator than of the code (the exact same code runs on a different machine, even in debug mode, I guess I should have mentioned that), it's hard to provide a MCVE.

Comment: @AracKnight If you can make a reproducible bug report, you might consider reporting a bug at https://bugreports.qt.io

Answer (score 0):

well i don't use QtDebugger but windbg seems to interpret it correctly

```
C:\>cdb -c ".formats 40a00000;q" cdb | grep -i Float
  Float:   low 5 high 0

C:\>
```

Regarding your comment [Maximum Float](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/floating-limits?view=vs-2017) possible is ~-3*10^38 so -10^39 isnt representable by a 32bit float

```
C:\>cdb -c ".formats ff7fffff;q" cdb | grep Float
  Float:   low -3.40282e+038 high 0

C:\>grep -inhr (\-FLT_MAX "c:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\*"
1117:        return -3.402823466e+38f; // Smallest float value (-FLT_MAX)

C:\>
```

Comment: Well, I even tried it with CDB as Debugger set in QtCreator, the same thing happened. Seems to be more a problem of the QtCreator than with the debugger itself.